# Create columns in SQL table that map to primary keys of other table

Tags: mysql, sql, .net

I have a Crops table where each row corresponds to one Crop.

In a separate table, Locations, I have each row corresponding to one location. I want to store the frequency of every crop in Crops in every location, among other things. Frequency obviously varies per crop and per location. **How would I structure the Location table?** I did some reading and thought foreign keys would possibly be useful, but I can't quite see how. I'm new to SQL.

What I'm essentially trying to do is store a list of data in my location table. Is there any way to make the columns of Locations correspond to the primary keys of Crops? A solution that would update Locations when Crops is updated would be fantastic as well.

Comment: Like Barmar said, you probably should create a Many-To-Many relationship, and to do that you would need a Junction Table, like it is explained here: https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/218734758-A-beginner-s-guide-to-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a separate many-to-many table:

```
CREATE TABLE CropLocations (
    crop_id INT NOT NULL,
    location_id INT NOT NULL,
    frequency INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (crop_id, location_id),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (crop_id) REFERENCES Crops (id),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES Locations (id)
);
```